# How can I align my navbar menu items to the right?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I am working on a navbar and I need to align some part of it to the right:

[image: what I want to achieve]

This is what i have :

[image: What i have done]

Also the collapse-navbar is not working , when I reduce the screen the collapse button appears but nothing happens when I click...
This is my codebase : [Codebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFGCG.png)

Comment: Use `justify-content-between` class into the `nav` element.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to demonstrate your problem here.

Comment: You should also take the [tour]. What you posted below is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with Bootstrap, hope it is to any help:

```css
.test {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-dark">
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <h1 class="test" href="#">Funds.</h1>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="test" href="#">Use funds for business </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="test" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="test" href="#">Legal stuff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Tidy button in the snippet editor would work wonders here, and you have a random closing button tag in there. Also, your first list's markup is invalid.